# Google Chrome do GET request after POST AJAX

Tags: google-chrome

I have a problem with Google Chrome. 
I try to post data from page to my MVC controller with AJAX and sometimes Chrome tries to do GET request after POST.

I saw that it happens in case when try to post data very frequently (push button 5-10 times with minimum delay) or in case when page doing nothing (stay) on the page about after 5-10 minutes.

```html
$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("PO_Comparison")',
            data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
            dataType: 'json',
            traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (result) {
                compare_with_data = result;
                $.when(fillData(result)).done(function () {
                    EditShow();
                    ComparingUnloadPopupBox();
                });
                $("#compare_image_please_wait").hide();
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error.statusText + "! Please reload the page.");
                ComparingUnloadPopupBox();
                $("#compare_image_please_wait").hide();
            }
        });
```

MVC controller part:

```html
 public JsonResult PO_Comparison( List<Project_Items> parameters)
{
//Updating my Project_Items
return Json(new{ data:compared_data }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);

}
```

[image]

Internet explorer and Firefox works fine.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem, Chrome 56, the post response is ignored and a get is executed. Did you find out why this is happening?